# Resource image file not showing at runtime. qt,c++

Tags: c++, qt

I have following structure for icon and resource file

```
mainDir/CheckBoxIcon/checkbox_checked.png
mainDir/Resource.qrc
```

in Resource.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file alias="checkbox_checked.png">CheckBoxIcon/checkbox_checked.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

in stylesheet I am using as

```
QCheckBox::indicator:checked 
{
    image: url(:/checkbox_checked.png);
}
```

## Result

icon image is not showing. Please help me. What is wrong with my implementation

Comment: Can you change to this in your .qrc : `<file alias="checked.png">CheckBoxIcon/checked.png</file>` then recompile your .qrc, and finally recompile your solution? No need to change the style sheet

Comment: Did you make sure to run Qmake first?

Comment: yea, I can see qrc_Resource.rcc file

Comment: Why did you remove the prefix?

Comment: Is the stylesheet also part of the qrc file or part of a ui file?
Is your qrc file in the same binary as the code where you want to access it from?

Comment: check your resource prefix !!!

Comment: stylesheet is not a part of qrc. I read it separately from external file